# Running a stepwise linear model with BIC criterion

Tags: r, lm

Is it possible to set a stepwise linear model to use the BIC criteria rather than AIC?

I've been trying this but it still calculates each step using AIC values rather than BIC

```
null = lm(data[,1] ~ 1)
full = lm(data[,1] ~ age + bmi + gender + group)
step(null, scope = list(lower=null,upper=full),
     direction="both", criterion = "BIC")
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add the argument `k=log(n)` to the `step` function (`n` number of samples in the model matrix)

From `?step`:

> Arguments:
>   ...
>
> **k** the multiple of the number of degrees of freedom used for the penalty.
>   Only k = 2 gives the genuine AIC; k = log(n) is sometimes referred to
>   as BIC or SBC.

Comment: `n` is the number of observations which has to be known, while `k` is the numeric value of penalty per parameter to be used.

Comment: Sorry for asking after such a long time, I tried your method putting $k=log n$ in the argument, but the resulted best model has a different BIC compared with if I do the BIC directly with these selected variables. Why is that? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is calculated differently, often the constant in the log-likelihood function gets omitted.