# Extract information criterion for each parameter in glm

Tags: r, glm

I'd like to extract either Akaike's Information Criterion (AIC), Bayesian Informaiton Criterion (BIC) or just the likelihood-ratio test (LRT) for each parameter in a call to `glm`.

Here's some example data

```
set.seed(12345)
x1 <- rnorm(100)
f1 <- factor(rbinom(100, size=2, prob=.5))
y <- rbinom(100, size=1, prob=1/(1 + exp(.7*x1 + (f1==2))))
fit <- glm(y ~ x1 + f1, family=binomial)
summary(fit)
```

Now when the code above is run I get

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)  0.09408    0.44406   0.212  0.83222   
x1          -0.74737    0.23484  -3.182  0.00146 **
f11         -0.02476    0.53768  -0.046  0.96327   
f12         -1.53873    0.67443  -2.282  0.02252 *
```

The `z value`s and corresponding p-values are based on Wald statistics but I'd like a LRT, AIC or BIC for each of the parameters in the model instead.

If I use `drop1()` then I can get the AIC and LRT for each *term* n the model formula. It's the same situation when using the `step()` function since it uses `drop1()` so only really accommodates changes in *terms* and not *parameters*. The problem is most obvious for categorical (factor) predictors.

```
> drop1(fit, test="LRT")
Single term deletions

Model:
y ~ x1 + f1
       Df Deviance    AIC     LRT  Pr(>Chi)    
<none>      117.66 125.66                      
x1      1   129.78 135.78 12.1198 0.0004989 ***
f1      2   125.81 129.81  8.1519 0.0169763 *
```

Does there exist any function that could achieve something similar for each *parameter*?

- I'm guessing it would be possible to run a series of model `update()`s but I was hoping that some of the functionality was already implemented somewhere.
- The squared Wald test is asymptotically equivalent to the LRT so it's easy to get an approximation from the Wald statistics. I was hoping to get the actual values instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a stepwise linear model with BIC criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400494/running-a-stepwise-linear-model-with-bic-criterion)

Comment: @jay.sf `step` uses `add1` and `drop1` repeatedly and works nicely with formula terms as mentioned above. The problem is to get the individual parameters (or essentially an easy way to extract the model formulae when setting a single parameter to zero). Have updated the question to stress that further.